# Div makes table larger instead of scrollbar

Tags: html, css, layout

Please look at this code example: http://jsfiddle.net/Voga/e6kB8/1/

If there are only 4 "A" characters the div and table nicely fills the total screen.

Now when I add more "A" characters, the table becomes larger and larger. I want that the table height stays the same but that the DIV gets a scrollbar when it contains too much lines. I tried everything but cannot find a solution.

Can somebody help me?

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tr class="small">
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="small">
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="scroll">
                A <br></br>
                A <br></br>
                A <br></br>
                A <br></br>
                A <br></br>
                A <br></br>
                A <br></br>
                ...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
body, html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.small{
    height:20px;
}

table{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
}

td{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
}

tr{
    vertical-align:top;
}

div{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with the table height should remain the same? As in maximum the table height should be 100% of the viewport... Do you want the scrollbar on the viewport or inside the table cell when the content of that cell would cause the table to be scrollable and be larger than the viewport (100% of the window's height?)

Comment: I want indeed that the tables keeps the size of the viewport and that a scrollbar is added to the div container.

Comment: You need IMHO JS for that.

Comment: So you suggests JavaScript that manually sets the height of the DIV with the rest value of the table? Because I also saw that when I give the DIV a fixed height so 400px instead of 100%, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `display:table;` from `div`, it works for me:

```
div{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display:table;
}
```

Also, if you change `overflow:scroll` to `overflow:auto` it'll remove the useless scroll when you have just a few elements...

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/2uFHe/)

Comment: This does not add a scroll bar to the div inside the cell.

Comment: This seems to work in Chrome but does not work in IE